# Insert text into a text file following specific text using Python

Tags: python, text

I have to edit some text files to include new information, but I will need to insert that information at specific locations in the file based on the surrounding text.

This doesn't work the way I need it to:

```
 with open(full_filename, "r+") as f:
        lines = f.readlines() 
        for line in lines:
            if 'identifying text' in line:   
                offset = f.tell()
                f.seek(offset)  
                f.write('Inserted text')
```

...in that it adds the text to the end of the file.  How would I write it to the next line following the identifying text?

(AFAICT, this is not a duplicate of similar questions, since none of those were able to provide this answer)

Comment: Short version: you can't insert.  You can overwrite, if what you want to "add" takes less space than what used to be there, but you can't simply insert a line and have the lines after it move down.  Is overwriting really what you want?  [Life is very much simpler if you don't need to work in-place, so you'll probably wind up doing that, I expect.]

Comment: @DSM In the end, all that matters is I have a new file that has the information inserted in there; it doesn't matter what intermediary steps I need to go through to do it.  The new file will even have a new filename.

Comment: Have you considered using sed? You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need to work in place, then maybe something like:

```
with open("old.txt") as f_old, open("new.txt", "w") as f_new:
    for line in f_old:
        f_new.write(line)
        if 'identifier' in line:
            f_new.write("extra stuff\n")
```

(or, to be Python-2.5 compatible):

```
f_old = open("old.txt")
f_new = open("new.txt", "w")

for line in f_old:
    f_new.write(line)
    if 'identifier' in line:
        f_new.write("extra stuff\n")

f_old.close()
f_new.close()
```

which turns

```
>>> !cat old.txt
a
b
c
d identifier
e
```

into

```
>>> !cat new.txt
a
b
c
d identifier
extra stuff
e
```

(Usual warning about using 'string1' in 'string2': 'name' in 'enamel' is True, 'hello' in 'Othello' is True, etc., but obviously you can make the condition arbitrarily complicated.)

Comment: The first line is throwing a syntax error.  I'm using Python 2.5.

Comment: Thanks for that 2.5 edit.  I had been using "from __future__ import with_statement" but I guess with changed even more since that time.

Comment: @Chelonian: yeah, in the old days you couldn't do two `with`s on a line, you have to nest 'em.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you happen to know if there is a quick way to expand this to allow for "if 'identifier' in line, *change* the next line (as opposed to adding a line"?

Comment: // , Sure! But you might want to code it out and try a few things yourself, first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex and then replace the text.

```
import re
c = "This is a file's contents, apparently you want to insert text"
re.sub('text', 'text here', c)
print c
```

returns "This is a file's contents, apparently you want to insert text here"

Not sure if it'll work for your usecase but it's nice and simple if it fits.

Comment: This won't perform for files larger than memory present.

Comment: True. Could you read one line at a time into memory to alleviate this?

Answer (score 1):

This will look for any string, in the file (not specific, to be at the start of the line only, i.e. can exist spread over multiple lines as well).

Typically you can follow the algo as:

1. lookup for the string in the file, and capture "location"
2. then split the file about this "location", and attempt to create new files as

   - write start-to-loc content to new file
   - next, write your "NEW TEXT" to the new file
   - next, loc-to-end content to new file

Let us see code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

SEARCH_WORD = 'search_text_here'
file_name = 'sample.txt'
add_text = 'my_new_text_here'

final_loc=-1
with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:
        fsize =  os.path.getsize(file_name)
        bsize = fsize
        word_len = len(SEARCH_WORD)
        while True:
                found = 0
                pr = file.read(bsize)
                pf = pr.find(SEARCH_WORD)
                if pf > -1:
                        found = 1
                        pos_dec = file.tell() - (bsize - pf)
                        file.seek(pos_dec + word_len)
                        bsize = fsize - file.tell()
                if file.tell() < fsize:
                                seek = file.tell() - word_len + 1
                                file.seek(seek)
                                if 1==found:
                                        final_loc = seek
                                        print "loc: "+str(final_loc)
                else:
                                break

# create file with doxygen comments
f_old = open(file_name,'r+')
f_new = open("new.txt", "w")
f_old.seek(0)
fStr = str(f_old.read())
f_new.write(fStr[:final_loc-1]);
f_new.write(add_text);
f_new.write(fStr[final_loc-1:])
f_new.close()
f_old.close()
```